# Memory usage of Shared Library in NFS mounted File system

Tags: linux, memory, shared-libraries

I am using a NFS mounted File system for Linux  based embedded system box. I have few shared libraries, sizes of which varies from 1MB to 20MB. I am running the application which is dependent on these libraries.

While running the application, i checked the /proc/*TaskPID*/smap.

```
Size:               4692 kB
Rss:                1880 kB
Pss:                1880 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:      1880 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:         1880 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

Now as per my understanding, it means that Library is partially loaded (Since RSS says lesser value to Size)? If so, on a reference to other portion, trying to get that part into memory (Hope my understanding is correct) will be more costlier in case of NFS mounted system.So can we make it load every thing before running?